# imagemin error [TypeError: (input, output, opts) => {

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-optimization, imagemin

```
function minBytes(originalFilePath, destinationFilePath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    var Imagemin = require('imagemin');

    console.log(originalFilePath) // /app/public/images/temporary/4du_QIGCJb5.jpeg
    console.log(destinationFilePath)  // /app/public/images/database/9d605a80a2cf926513b7fb/4du_QIGCJb5-0.jpeg

    var imagemin = new Imagemin()
      .src(originalFilePath)
      .dest(destinationFilePath);
    imagemin.run(function (error, files) {
      if (error != null) {
        console.log(error)
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log(files);
        resolve(destinationFilePath);
      }
    });
  });
};

var minBytesResult = yield Promise.resolve( minBytes(originalFilePath, destinationFilePath) );
```

When I use imagemin get error like below, did I miss something ?

```
[TypeError: (input, output, opts) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(input)) {
    return Promise.reject(new TypeError('Expected an arr...<omitted>...
  } is not a constructor]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the v4.0.0 way of using imagemin.

Install: `npm install imagemin@4.0.0` and your code will work

Comment: Thanx @tsouza you saved me!! :D